# Android - playback audio on internal phone speaker with bluetooth speaker connected

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

My setup: Android 4.4 tablet connected with Sony bluetooth speakers.
Spotify is playing music on the bluetooth speaker.

Using

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), 0);
soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0);
SoundBeeps = soundPool.load(this,R.raw.beeps,1);
soundPool.play(SoundBeeps, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);`
```

the notification sound is played back on both the internal and the bluetooth speaker.

Is it possible to play a notification sound **only** on the tablet's internal speaker, not on the bluetooth speaker?

Answer (score 1):

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0);
```

the argument `AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION` here is responsibe to make it play in that manner
I have not tried this but type this `AudioManager.STREAM_` and hit ctrl+space you will get recommendations and use each one and test

Comment: Thank you, I've tried: AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM => internal + bt speaker, AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF => only bt speaker, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC => only bt speaker, AudioManager.STREAM_RING => internal + bt speaker, 
AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM => only bt speaker, 
AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL => only bt speaker;
unfortunately there's no stream that outputs the sound only on the device speaker...

Comment: @Martin do you have solution now? Can u post it?

Comment: With wired headphones, `STREAM_RING` plays on device+headphones, and `STREAM_ALARM` always plays on device.